# Find Regex Expression only after finding a given String

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a **method that receives a text and a string** and use **regex to find a datetime**, associated with the given string.

**I don't know the position of the regex match**. It can be everywhere and change overtime since the text is editable. The following example have 3 options, but can have 10, 25 or even 100.

At the moment, i already created the method that founds the datetime however it is the first match and not the one after the given string.

```
private static DateTime getLastExecutionTime(string text, string nameFile)
{
    string lastRun = string.Empty;

    if (Regex.IsMatch(text, nameFile))
    {
        lastRun = Regex.Match(text, "[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}").ToString();

        return DateTime.Parse(lastRun);
    }

    return nullDate;
}
```

```
    =============
    INPUT EXAMPLE
    =============
    text = "Cat 01-08-2019 16:32\r\nDog 03-08-2019 12:32\r\nBear 13-07-2019 19:22"
    nameFile = "Dog"

    ===============
    EXPECTED OUTPUT
    ===============
    lastRun = "03-08-2019 12:32"
```

Comment: It is better in this case to find the line without Regex and just use Regex to pase the date from the line once it is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option will be to remove all the text before your nameFile by using Substring and IndexOf.

```
private static DateTime getLastExecutionTime(string text, string nameFile)
{
    string lastRun = string.Empty;

    if (Regex.IsMatch(text, nameFile))
    {
        lastRun = Regex.Match(text.Substring(text.IndexOf(nameFile)), " [0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}").ToString();

        return DateTime.Parse(lastRun);
    }

    return new DateTime();
}
```

You can also used a full regex solution :

```
private static DateTime getLastExecutionTime(string text, string nameFile)
{
    string lastRun = Regex.Match(text, "(?:" + nameFile + ") ([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})").Groups[1].Value;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastRun))
        return new DateTime();

    return DateTime.Parse(lastRun);
}
```

Comment: I believe the first option suggested is great. Substring the text until the given string and then do the regex expression. I am not sure if it is the more efficient. I am going to run some tests in both your suggestions.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If your date recogniser is the name of the file, you need to add it to the regular expression.
In this example, this `Regex.Match` will find a date followed by "Dog".

```
var matches = Regex.Match(text, "Dog ([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9])");
```

Or in a more generic way:

```
    var matches = Regex.Match(text, nameFile + " ([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9])");
```

In this case, you you need to access the "Group1" of the match result. The group at index 0 will return the match without the groups.

```
matches[0].Groups[1].Value
```

More about MatchCollection:
[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I don't really want the last one because i can have more than 2 names.
For example: ""Cat 01-08-2019 16:32\r\nDog 03-08-2019 12:32\r\nCow 02-08-2019 10:50\r\nBear 18-07-2019 19:22"

Comment: So which one do you want? Access the matchCollection[1] for a second one.

Comment: I don't really know which is the position. The example had 2, and i already changed for 3. But can have 10, 100. Can even change overtime.

Comment: You I dont understand how do you expect to know which date is relevant.

Comment: The date that is relevant to me is the one that follows the given string (nameFile)

Comment: Updated my answer. Pay attention that I added a group operator ( ) around the date pattern.

Comment: EyIM i am testing your general solution and i am not getting any match.

Comment: My bad. please test now without string interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression:

```
Regex.Match(text, "^Dog (.+)$", RegexOptions.Multiline).Groups[1].Value
```

For your input in a `text` variable the output is: `03-08-2019 12:32`

If you need to parametrize it, go ahead:

```
Regex.Match(text, $"^{query} (.+)$", RegexOptions.Multiline).Groups[1].Value
```

But make sure you're receiving the `query` from a trusted source, to prevent injection attacks.

You can quickly test expression here: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

We can try doing a one-liner regex replacement using the following pattern:

```
^[\s\S]*([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})[\s\S]*$
```

Script:

```
string text = "Cat 01-08-2019 16:32\r\nDog 03-08-2019 12:32";
string pattern = @"^[\s\S]*([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})[\s\S]*$";
string output = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "$1");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

This prints:

```
03-08-2019 12:32
```